# Как перевести строку в массив и оставить только цифры JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Требуется все числа, которые встречаются в строке, поместить в отдельный целочисленный массив. Функция должна возвращать этот массив.

Например: "djhf117 gf4 h008dbsh79".
При том что регулярные выражения нельзя использовать.
Должно возвращать массив чисел [117,4,0,0,8,79]

Пример:
введите сюда код

```js
let math = 'djhf123 gf6 h006dbsh90';

let getNumbers = function(string) {
  const numArray = []; // Возвращаемый результат
  let numStr = ''; // Аккумулятор для цифр
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(string[i]))) { // Если символ является числом
      if (string[i] !== '') {
        if (numStr === '0');
        numStr += string[i];
        // numArray.push(Number(numStr))
        continue;
      }
      if (numStr === '0') { // Если это 0, сразу добавляем в массив    
        if (string[i] !== ' ')
          numStr += string[i];
        numArray.push(Number(numStr)) // Это не ноль, добавляем в 
        //аккумулятор 

      } else {
        string[i] += numStr;
        continue;
      }

    } else {
      if (numStr !== '') {
        // Если в аккумуляторе что то есть, пушим
        numArray.push(Number(numStr));
        numStr = ''; // и зануляем аккумулятор
      }
    }
  }
  if (numStr !== '') numArray.push(Number(numStr));
  return numArray;
}
console.log(getNumbers(math));
```

Comment: Регулярными выражениями было бы попроще мне кажется: `str.match(/(?<![1-9])0|\d+/g)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Такой вариант думаю будет попроще:

```js
const someString = 'djhf117 gf4 h008dbsh79';

const getAllNumbers = str => {
  const result = [];

  str.split('').reduce((acc, curr, index) => { // дробим строку на массив и начинаем прогон
    if (Number(curr)) { // проверяем, что элемент является number или 0 (чтобы обойти falsey)
      if (index === str.length - 1) { // если у нас последний элемент строки, тогда пушим то, что имеем
        result.push(Number(acc += curr));
      }

      return acc ? acc += curr : curr; // если acc не undefined, тогда плюсуем к нему взятый элемент, иначе установливаем значение аккумулятора
    }

    if (acc) { // если curr не является числом, тогда пушим готовый аккумулятор в result
      result.push(Number(acc));
    }

    if (curr === '0') { // предположительно ошибочная проверка
      result.push(Number(curr));
    }
  }, undefined); // инициализируем значение аккумулятора

  return result;
}

console.log(getAllNumbers(someString));
```

Comment: Ваш код возвращает не тот результат, который ожидается

Comment: @SwaD да, вы правы, поправил, но больше похоже на ошибку в тз

Comment: А через perseInt, разве не удобнее перебрать цифры?

Comment: @Saveliy можно и через parseInt, не суть, тут вопрос задачи только в том, как вычленить числа из строки и если эти числа занимают диапазон строки.

Comment: и если использовать parseInt, то вместо split и reduce?

Comment: @Saveliy parseInt переводит строку в числа, если это возможно, иначе вернет NaN (not a number) и если вы имеете ввиду просто скормить строку в парсер, то так не получится.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let math = 'djhf117 gf4 h008dbsh79';

function getNumbers() {
    const numArray = []; // Возвращаемый результат
    let numStr = ''; // Аккумулятор для цифр
    for (let i = 0; i < math.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(Number(math[i]))) { // Если символ является числом
            if (math[i] === '0') { // Если это 0, сразу добавляем в массив
                numArray.push(Number(math[i]))
            } else { // Это не ноль, добавляем в аккумулятор
                numStr += math[i]
            }
        } else { // Встретилось не число
            if (numStr.length) { // Если в аккумуляторе что то есть, пушим
                numArray.push(Number(numStr));
                numStr = ''; // и зануляем аккумулятор
            }
        }
    }
    return numArray;
}

console.log(getNumbers())
```

Comment: @SwaDэтот ответ мне более понятен,хоть он и не доработан,но разве через parseInt не удобнее перебирать числа? Или каждому своё)

Comment: @Saveliy У меня доработан :) Хотя его кто-то считает почему-то сложным....

Comment: Для меня он немного сложнее, чем выше пример, просто не могу понять в чем ошибка или не дописан код....

Answer (score 0):

В ответах [SwaD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1455319/385375) и [MrYogurt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1455321/385375) есть проблемы с обработкой нуля. Если вместо последовательности `'008'` будет последовательность `'1008'`, то в результатах не увидите число `1008`

Предлагаю очень простой алгоритм без этого недочёта (и как по мне с более читабельным кодом):

1. Является ли символ числом или нет, я вместо преобразований, предлагаю использовать проверку с помощью кода символа строки. Код 48 отвечает за символ нуля, потому при проверке стоит строгое неравенство
2. Объявляем массив, куда будем класть все числа
3. Объявляем переменную, куда будем складывать по одному символы, отвечающие за цифры
4. С помощью цикла [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) перебираем по одному все символы строки:

   4.1. Если символ - это цифра и не ноль, то добавляем его в переменную строку иначе переходим к следующему символу

   4.2. Если символ - это ноль, то смотрим на пустоту переменной строки. Если она пустая, значит мы встретили одиночный ноль, а значит надо его просто добавить в массив. Если она не пустая, то значит мы встретили ноль, который является продолжением другого числа, значит надо добавить в переменную строку. Переходим к следующему символу

   4.3. Если встретили не цифру, то смотрим на пустоту переменной строки, если она пустая, то переходим к следующему символу, а если не пустая, то добавляем в массив преобразовав его в число
5. Если после окончания цикла у нас переменная строка осталась не пустой, то добавлем это в массив преобразовав его в число
6. Возвращаем массив

Код:

```js
const isDigitButNotZero = (symbol) => {
  const code = symbol.charCodeAt(0);

  return code > 48 && code <= 57;
}

const getNums = (str) => {
  const nums = [];
  let num = '';

  for (const symbol of str) {
    if (isDigitButNotZero(symbol)) {
      num += symbol;
      
      continue;
    }
    
    if (symbol === '0') {
      if (num !== '') num += symbol;
      else nums.push(+num);
      
      continue;
    }

    if (num !== '') {
      nums.push(+num);
      num = '';
    }
  }

  if (num !== '') nums.push(+num);

  return nums;
}

const nums1 = getNums('djhf117 gf4 h008dbsh79');
const nums2 = getNums('djhf117 gf4 h1008dbsh79');

console.log(nums1);
console.log(nums2);
```

Comment: По поводу "1008", это уже додумывание тз и кейс по нулям описан криво, так что предположительно все 3 решения неправильны, а проверки на знаки в вашем решении, как по мне, моветон.

Comment: @MrYogurt Причём тут додумывание? Если `'117'` - то `117`, то `'1008'` - это `1008`. Это просто элементарная логика, а не додумывание. На счёт знаков не понимаю вашу претензию

Comment: Если смотреть с точки зрения выдачи в прод, то такой код не понятен интуитивно, чтобы вмешаться в алгоритм, придется гуглить char id, что как по мне антипаттерн.

Comment: @MrYogurt Ну если нет знаний в чём-то то придётся это гуглить) А так указание диапазона с помощью `charId` не такая уж и редкость. Даже в регулярных выражениях очень часто используют диапазон, так что судя по названию функции и опыту вполне можно сразу понять что происходит

Comment: Использования регулярок тоже стоит избегать в реальных задачах, иначе вместо проблемы, которую решает регулярка, появляется еще одна, когда нужно изменить функционал. Ну а проверка диапазона в регулярках выглядит вполне интуитивно, по сравнению с id знаков, например match(/[0-9]/), если правильно написал.

Comment: @MrYogurt Ну во первых регулрки надо избегать там где действительно в этом есть необходимость. Да их плодить - это зло, но она вполне себе нужные вещи. А на счёт интуитивности, я повторюсь имя опыт в регулярках, учитывая название функции и имея нужные знанения и опыт в JS, то становится очевидно что именно просиходит в куске кода. Возможно начинающим будет сложно это понять, но я и не ориентируюсь на людей без опыта и знанний

Comment: Оперировать потенциальным опытом и знаниями все таки некорректно, ибо по правилам хорошего код стайла, все должно быть понятно даже джуну. Очевидно, что можно писать олимпиадный код в 1 строку, но читать то его кто потом будет? Всегда приятно, когда логика понятна при беглом взгляде, если возвращаешься к функционалу спустя какое то время или делегируешь задачу на менее опытного.

Comment: @MrYogurt Я не думаю что `charId` явлется чем-то олимпиадным, знания даже у джуна должно быть. Знать что каждому символу соответствует определённое число - это не что-то тайное, об этом пишут на всех начальных курсах, котрые я повидал. Как минимум сравнение строк должен знать джун и там явно используется код символов. Даже если такие простые вещи кажется сложными, я вынес определение числа в отдельную функцию и назвал его соответственно. Так что можно и не углубляться джуну, а просто пользоваться функцией. Вы первый кто мне сказал, что работа с `charId` является чем-то сложным для кого-то

Comment: Я не говорил, что работа с айдишниками является сложной, просто для человеческого восприятия не очевидна, ничего более, ведь мы не держим айдишники каждого знака в голове и чтобы банально задебажить такую проверку, человек должен погуглить айдишники, если с ними не работает активно (а оно так и есть зачастую). Мы тут конечно демагогию разводим, просто хотел для начинающего подчеркнуть, что в реальных задачах лучше писать более очевидно, т.к. это просто выгоднее для бизнеса.

Comment: @MrYogurt Ну в голове держать и не нужно, зная сам факт того что есть такая вещь уже понятно бывает что там просиходит) На счёт более очевидного кода спорить не стану, но я и не сторонник того, чтобы человек вообще не разбирался в том что происходит в коде. Такие знания позволяют писать более оптимальный код, хоть и менее очевидный. Ну и если код не очень понятный, человек может просто оперировать грамотными названиями, чтобы понять что к чему

Comment: @EzioMercer Вы очень понятно разъяснили. Подскажите пожалуйста, я делал по вашему образцу и у меня не выходит просмотреть еще один ноль и добавить его,  или же когда хочу его добавить ,добавляются два 0,где я запутался? Код написал в вопросе.

Comment: @Saveliy Я не очень понимаю зачем вы проверяете это `if (string[i] !== ' ')`, если уже убедились что у вас на входе цифра? И не очень понимаю зачем вы пытаетесь менять мой код?)) Если вам что-то не понятно в моём коде, можете сказать, объясню поподробнее

Answer (score 0):

Можно что-то такое сделать..

```js
let m = 'djhf117 gf4 h008db0101sh79h7';

function f(m) {
  let res = [], str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(m[i])) continue;
    if (str == '' && m[i] == 0) { res.push(+m[i]); continue }
    str += m[i];
    if (isNaN(m[i + 1])) { res.push(+str); str = ''; i++ }        
  }
  return res
}
console.log(f(m));
```